# Is there any better method without subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some data like this:

| TYPE | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 5 | 6 | 2022-05-01 |
| aaa | 8 | 7 | 2022-05-08 |
| aaa | 9 | 8 | 2022-05-16 |
| bbb | 7 | 4 | 2022-05-09 |
| bbb | 6 | 8 | 2022-05-14 |
| bbb | 3 | 3 | 2022-05-25 |

I need to get an output like this:

| TYPE | A | D | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 22 | 8 | 2022-05-16 |
| bbb | 16 | 3 | 2022-05-25 |

My current code :

```
SELECT type, SUM(A) AS A, SUM(D) AS D, MAX(C) AS C
FROM
    (SELECT 
         type, A, B, C,
         CASE 
             WHEN C = MAX(C) OVER(PARTITION BY type) 
                 THEN B
                 ELSE 0
         END AS D,
     FROM
         data) AS bbb
GROUP BY
    type
```

Is there any better method without using a subquery?

I'm using SQL Server.

Comment: Define better??

Comment: without using a subquery.

Comment: Why is that "better"?

Comment: I think less 'select' will increase speed , is it right??

Comment: SQL is a declarative language I.e. you tell the engine what results you want, and it works out how to obtain them. For the most part you cannot make any performance predictions from the query, you need to inspect the execution plan and analyse the performance that way.

Comment: not necessary. Run both provided answer against your data and see which is better

Comment: *"I think less 'select' will increase speed"* length of query <> speed of query. A short query can be very unperformant, and a long query performant. Shorter certainly doesn't equat to "better".

Comment: In addition, when asking a question you should tell us what you are really trying to accomplish i.e. In this case a more perfomant query. Then you will get the correct assistance. There is no guarantee that the answers provided perform any better than your original, because you didn't ask for that.

Comment: Thank you guys, I learn SQL for two months, your comments will help me make progress quickly, I also learn how to ask good question next time,  thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are asking for a query without a subquery, you can try this one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TYPE,
  SUM(A) OVER(PARTITION BY TYPE) AS A,
  FIRST_VALUE(B) OVER(PARTITION BY TYPE ORDER BY C DESC) AS D,
  MAX(C) OVER(PARTITION BY TYPE) AS C
FROM data;
```

Output:

| TYPE | A | D | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 22 | 8 | 2022-05-16 00:00:00.000 |
| bbb | 16 | 3 | 2022-05-25 00:00:00.000 |

See this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=1a26bf0eaa43029b46e5fabc022a9a01) demo.

Comment: you got my point! thank you

Answer (score 4):

Here is one approach using `ROW_NUMBER` along with pivoting logic:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TYPE ORDER BY C DESC) rn
    FROM data
)

SELECT TYPE, SUM(A) AS A,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN B END) AS D,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN C END) AS C
FROM cte
GROUP BY TYPE;
```

Here is a working [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=65558a0aeeac96f4fca6d0c8616053d5).